# its my modal How to show modal popup after time delay using react hooks

Tags: reactjs, popup

its my modal How to show modal popup after time delay  using react hooks its like a ad in my pagee it should be shown after some time of initizal page load

```
  const [open, setOpen] = React.useState(false);
  const handleOpen = () => setOpen(true);
  const handleClose = () => setOpen(false);
  return (
    <div>
      <Button onClick={handleOpen}>Open modal</Button>
      <Modal
        open={open}
        onClose={handleClose}
        aria-labelledby="modal-modal-title"
        aria-describedby="modal-modal-description"
      >
        <Box sx={style}>
          <Typography id="modal-modal-title" variant="h6" component="h2">
            Text in a modal
          </Typography>
          <Typography id="modal-modal-description" sx={{ mt: 2 }}>
            Duis mollis, est non commodo luctus, nisi erat porttitor ligula.
          </Typography>
        </Box>
      </Modal>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Should it be both opened automatically and have a button to open it? If it is like an ad, do you still need a button to open the modal? Is it a possible scenario when user clicks on a button quickly and closes it, before it opens automatically? If so, should the modal be opened after user opening and closing it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what you can do is modify your handleOpen function in this way:

```
const handleOpen = () => {
   const timer =  setTimeout(() => {
        setOpen(true);
    }, 1000)
     return () => clearTimeout(timer);
}
```

and if you want to automatically open your modal/Add you can use useEffect this way:

```
useEffect(() => {
    handleOpen();
}, [])
```

Answer (score 0):

I think `useEffect` able to solve your problem. Example:

```
  const [open, setOpen] = React.useState(false);
  const handleOpen = () => setOpen(true);
  const handleClose = () => setOpen(false);

  // show modal in 1 sec after mounted
  useEffect(() => {
    const timer = setTimeout(() => {
      setOpen(true);
    }, 1000);
    // clear timer if the component unmount
    return () => clearTimeout(timer);
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <Button onClick={handleOpen}>Open modal</Button>
      <Modal
        open={open}
        onClose={handleClose}
        aria-labelledby="modal-modal-title"
        aria-describedby="modal-modal-description"
      >
        <Box sx={style}>
          <Typography id="modal-modal-title" variant="h6" component="h2">
            Text in a modal
          </Typography>
          <Typography id="modal-modal-description" sx={{ mt: 2 }}>
            Duis mollis, est non commodo luctus, nisi erat porttitor ligula.
          </Typography>
        </Box>
      </Modal>
    </div>
  );
```

Your modal will be shown 1 sec after mounted